# Sim 7080 AT Commands to connect to AWS IOT via MQTTS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, iot, at-command, aws-iot

I have problems connecting to AWS IOT using MQTT with the simcom 7080G. I am following the guide from the file SIM7080_Series_MQTT(S)_Application_Note_V1.01.pdf [link](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/8/8e/SIM7080_Series_MQTT%28S%29_Application_Note_V1.01.pdf).

I follwed the section 5.2 MQTTS Function.

I have an NB-IOT network connection established:

```
AT+CNACT?
+CNACT: 0,1,"10.110.7.XXX"
+CNACT: 1,0,"0.0.0.0"
+CNACT: 2,0,"0.0.0.0"
+CNACT: 3,0,"0.0.0.0"
OK
```

Afterwards I am sending the following commands and I get an OK response from all of them except the AT+SMCONN!!:

```
AT+CFSINIT
AT+CFSWFILE=3,"ca.crt",0,1168,5000           (-> here I am seding the AmazonRootCa1.pem downloaded from AWS)
AT+CFSWFILE=3,"myclient.crt",0,1204,5000     (-> this is the xxx-certificate.pem.crt file downloaded from AWS)
AT+CFSWFILE=3,"myclient.key",0,1652,5000     (->this is the xxx-private.pem.key file downloaded from AWS)
AT+CFSTERM
 
AT+SMCONF=URL,xxx.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com,8883
AT+SMCONF=KEEPTIME,600
AT+SMCONF="CLIENTID","pico1"
At+CSSLCFG="SSLVERSION",0,3
AT+CSSLCFG="CONVERT",2,"ca.crt"
AT+CSSLCFG="CONVERT",1,"myclient.crt","myclient.key"
AT+SMSSL=1,"ca.crt","myclient.crt"
AT+SMCONN
```

What am I doing wrong? is there something I am missing?

Comment: what is the policy attached to the certificate in AWS IoT?

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck at the same problem as your situation, AT+SMCONN was failed by error.
what is the firmware version of your T-SIM7080G, mine is 1951B05SIM7080.

I followed the guidance from https://github.com/botletics/SIM7000-LTE-Shield/issues/58 but still go nowhere.

*"Whatever url AWS gives you for your IoT Core endpoint, you have to strip out the "-ats" from it. So "a1k9ecig9j720o-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" becomes "a1k9ecig9j720o.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
You need to use the legacy root certificate provided by AWS here under "VeriSign Endpoints (legacy)". NOTE some regions apparently don't support legacy certs, so it seems the SIM7000 won't work in those."*

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect to aws, with the same AT-commands as you describe.
Additionally I set in the aws management console, under settings -> "Device data endpoint" the security policy to a TLS1.2 policy (default was TLS1.3). Also check in Security -> Policies -> <your device> that the policy allows the access to your topic.

Answer (score 0):

After much tries, I found the solution. Disable the RTCTime  checking in the CSSLCFG stage. these are the steps i have taken to connect to AWS. Hopefully this works for you
## configure MQTT parameters

```
    AT+SMCONF=\\\"URL\\\",xxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com,8883
    AT+SMCONF=\\\"CLIENTID\\\"xxxxxx\"
    AT+SMCONF=\\\"KEEPTIME\\\",60,
    AT+SMCONF=\\\"CLEANSS\\\",1
    AT+SMCONF=\\\"QOS\\\",1
    AT+SMCONF?

    ## configure SSL parameters
    AT+CSSLCFG=\\\"SSLVERSION\\\",0,3
    AT+CSSLCFG=\\\"IGNORERTCTIME\\\",0,1
    AT+CSSLCFG=\\\"CONVERT\\\",2,rootCA.pem
    AT+CSSLCFG=\\\"CONVERT\\\",1,deviceCert.crt,devicePKey.key
    
    AT+SMSSL=1,rootCA.pem,deviceCert.crt
   AT+SMSSL?

    ## attempt connection
    AT+SMCONN  # connect to MQTT
    AT+SMDISC # disconnect from MQTT
    AT+SMSTATE? , # inquire MQTT connection status (0=disconnected, 1=connected, 2=session present)
```